# Finding the path over which to compute a complex line integral when converted from a real integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I have the integral
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{5+3\cos t}dt.$$
And I want to convert this to a complex line integral.

My idea was to use $\cos t=(e^{it}+e^{-it})/2$, but what is the path $a$ over which I integrate? And does the integral become $\int_a\frac{1}{5+3/2(e^{it}+e^{-it})}dt$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the change of variable $z = e^{it} $, then:
$$\cos t = \frac {z+z^{-1}}{2} \quad dt = \frac {dz}{iz}$$
and the path is the unit circle.

Comment: And is the path then $[0,2\pi]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}, t\mapsto e^{it}$?

Comment: Yes, the map $t \mapsto e^{it} =z$ sends $[0, 2\pi]$ to the unit circle.